# Managing development of 2+ nodejs packages with dependencies

Tags: node.js, git, package, npm

I am developing 2 node.js packages, each managed in their own git repository. Package `B` depends on package `A`, so my local directory structure looks like this:

```
A1/
B/
  node_modules/
    A2/
```

If I make a change to the local code of `A1`, I would like to test it with `B` before pushing it to the public repository. How can I do this?

In it's current state, `B` has it's own local copy (`A2`), so it is referencing a different version. `B` is a public package, so I would like to avoid directly modifying the source code of `B` to reference `A1`.

One possible solution is to have 2 local copies of `B`: `B1` is the released, public version that has it's own local dependency on `A2`, and `B2` is my own private version that directly references `A1` using something like `require('./../A1')`.

```
A1/
B1/
  node_modules/
    A2/
B2/
```

This seems kind of ugly (and would force me to maintain 2 copies of `B`), and I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplest case symlinks will do the trick. But you may go further and use some kind of fancy build system like grunt, gulp and so forth.
I'm using classic make scripts for all of my projects. So you can just copy one project into another before testing it e.g:

```
NPM = /usr/bin/env npm
MODULES = ./node_modules/
PROJECTS_PATH = ../
DEPENDENCY = project_a/

default: test

test: copy
    $(NPM) test

copy:
    @rm -rf $(MODULES)$(DEPENDENCY)
    @cp -r $(PROJECTS_PATH)$(DEPENDENCY) $(MODULES)$(DEPENDENCY)

install:
    @rm -rf $(MODULES)
    $(NPM) install

.PHONY: test
```

It is not the best build script but it will do the job. Most unix systems will have `make` installed. So it is pretty portable too.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I just discovered `npm link` as well, which will handle symlink creation for me. Your `makefile` solution (or grunt) will be good for more complicated setups.